# Как правильно записать коллекцию содержащую большое количество данных в файл?

Tags: c#

Помогите разобраться, есть коллекция List<Dictionary<string, string>>, в данном случаи количества словарей может достигать 8 000 000 штук, при этом в каждом содержится от 10 до 12 пар ключей и значений, как можно сохранить такую коллекцию в файл?
Пробовал сериализовать в JSON, но для сериализации не хватает памяти, программа падает с ошибкой нехватки памяти, может кто-нибудь знает как решить такую проблему?

P. S. Файл нужен для последующего сравнения, без него не обойтись

Comment: А что Вам нужно сохранять? `Key`-`Value` из `Dictionary`?

Comment: Я думаю тут очень простая структура json и ее очень просто сделать руками, без серелизатора. Подготавливайте сами в строке (желательно через StringBuilder) Собирайте и пишите напрямую в файл, но пачками(сколько вам брать словарей в пачку определитесь уже сами).

Comment: Да, мне необходимо сохранить key/value из всех 8 000 000 словарей

Comment: Может лучше в базу писать? )  Но так то да, пишите "вручную" как будто `JSON`, ничего сложного там нет. Только скобки, запятые и кавычки расставить.

Comment: А смысл сериализовать в JSON? Может проще сериализовать в бинарник?

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Удивлён, сколько тут советов, как объехать проблему на костылях, что конечно тоже может решить её, а нормальное и самое простое решение никто не подсказал.

Можно же сериализовать сразу в файловый поток, а не в строку:

```cs
// List<Dictionary<string, string>> data;
using var fs = File.Create("file.json");
await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(fs, data);
```

Точно так же можно десереализовать из файла. При работе с большими данными лучше забыть про вычитывание текста полностью в память, тем более в `string`.

---

Добавлю пояснение для тех, кому неочевидна суть решения.

```cs
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
```

Вот этот способ требует выделения памяти под очень большую строку. Представьте, что она будет более миллиарда символов длиной, а под каждый символ нужно минимум 2 байта. То есть можно упереться в максимальную (по умолчанию) длину строки в байтах - 2 гигабайта, либо вообще закончится память на компьютере.

При сериализации в файловый поток выделение памяти для строки не требуется, так как запись при сериализации пойдет напрямую в файл. Следовательно и проблема, озвученная в вопросе

> Пробовал сериализовать в JSON, но для сериализации не хватает памяти, программа падает с ошибкой нехватки памяти

будет решена.

Comment: Цитата из вопроса: "Пробовал сериализовать в JSON, но для сериализации не хватает памяти, программа падает с ошибкой нехватки памяти"

Comment: @ZecosMAX дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Для начала, не до конца понятно то, в каком формате вы хотите сохранять ваши данные. Будет ли это сырой формат в котором явно задаётся и разделяется отдельных словарь? или это будет XML? или это будет JSON?

Если предположить, что формат самый простой из возможных учитывая то что вы хотите это позже использовать для сравнения, то я могу порекомендовать следующие варианты оптимизации.

1. Использовать класс `StreamWriter` таким образом вы создадите файл и откроете его для записи, запишете туда данные через буфер Windows и только потом закроете, это будет во много раз быстрее чем, скажем, использовать `System.IO.File.AppendAllText(...)` т.к. вы не будете дёргать файл на открытие при каждой итерации.
   Тогда код будет выглядеть так:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> list = ...;
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(path))
{
    foreach(var dict in list)
    {
        foreach(var kvp in dict)
        {
             sw.WriteLine(...); // формируем строку в файле
        }
    }
}
```

2. Для формирования строки файла, использовать класс `StringBuilder`
   он как раз может выполнять различные операции над строками эффективнее чем стандартные операторы над типом `string`, хотя это становится менее читаемым кодом, как по мне.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var dict in list)
foreach(var kvp in dict)
{
    sb.Clear();
    sb.Append("Key: ");
    sb.Append(kvp.Key);
    sb.Append(",Value: ");
    sb.Append(kvp.Value);

    sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

Здесь не будет переполнений памяти, т.к. не создаётся множество лишних объектов, а stringbuilder очищается на каждой итерации. Можно так же добавить лимит на размер StreamWriter'a и когда тот достигает определённого размера, сбрасывать изменения на диск при помощи `sw.Flush()` Это всё что можно сказать учитывая отсутствие формата... но тут не сложно придумать как прикрутить формат.

Надеюсь это поможет в понимании :)

Comment: Flush вызывать необязательно, у файлового потока фиксированный буфер. Flush может только все замедлить из-за более частых обращений к диску.

Comment: Конечно же Flush замедлит. Я не уверен насчёт размера буфера файлового потока, и свободной оперативной памяти, имеющейся у человека, потому, предложил сделать имплементацию своего собственного размера буфера и скидывать изменения на диск, если буфер становится больше.

Таким образом можно торговать использованием памяти взамен скорости и наоборот